# Need to redirect to image when referer is not empty

Tags: php, referer

The problem is when the referer is not empty I still get the link instead of the image.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != " "){
  $goodreferer = 0;
}   
else {
  $goodreferer = 1;
}

$image = 'http://www.example.com/imglink.gif';
$url = 'http://example.net/';

if ($show = 1 && $goodreferer = 1) {
  header("Location: ".$url);
} 
else {
  header("Location: ".$image);
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried `if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']) $goodreferer = 1; else $goodreferer = 0;`

Comment: Check your operators: `=` and `==`

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a value to the variable, instead of comparing.

- `=` means assigment, `$variable = 5` means variable is now equal to five.
- `==` means comparison, `$variable == 5` will return whether the variable is equal to five.

Also, PHP has a built-in function to check for emptiness of a string. `empty()`.

So the corrected version:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $goodreferer = 0;
}
else {
    $goodreferer = 1;
}

$image = 'http://www.imglink.gif';
$url   = 'http://link.com';

if ($show == 1 && $goodreferer == 1) {

    header("Location: " . $url);
}
else {
    header("Location: " . $image);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response, it's not working as i expected, first off have I misunderstood the referer empty / not empty? - when the script is loaded in the website the referer is empty, when the script is loaded directly from the address bar the referer is not empty, correct?

Comment: @mixer: Referer *should* be filled with the page the user used to get to your page. That's not always the case though, it's not 100% reliable. Referer would be empty if you typed the address in your address bar, and *should* not be empty if you clicked a link which led you to this page.

Comment: so the code above says when the referer is empty go to the image, but it still goes to the url when typed?

Comment: @mixer: Also, unless you're defining `$show` somewhere, the condition will always be FALSE, and you always get to the image. Like I said, Referer isn't 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != " "` with `!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`
Also use `$show == 1 && $goodreferer == 1` as Madara pointed.